# Is there a way (hack) to enable Screen Lock but NOT to Lock on lid close?

Tags: power-management, lock-screen

Here's exactly what I wanted to do: Turn ON Lock (`Settings` > `Brightness and Lock`), set the time to wait (`Lock screen after:`), BUT NOT to lock the screen (e.g. no Password prompt) if I'd only close (and of course open) the lid.

I'm not sure if there's some tweak/hack to be able to do that.

(I'm always walking out of my desk but my machine always does something, so "Do nothing" on lid close, but it's a little annoying to keep typing the password like 4x an hour. I need to have it lid closed. BUT, sometimes I do leave my desk for more than an hour and forgot to Ctrl+Alt+L. I'd like it to lock automatically like after an hour of inactivity. If scripting is the only way to do it, can you please help me where to start? Thanks in advance.)

Ubuntu 12.04.02, LightDM, Gnome Shell

Comment: Try running `acpi_listen` in a terminal, then close your laptop lid and open it after a few seconds. Does this command output anything to you?

Comment: I tried it 3 times (close, open), and this is the result:

button/lid LID0 00000080 00000024
button/lid LID0 00000080 00000025
button/lid LID0 00000080 00000026
button/lid LID0 00000080 00000027
button/lid LID0 00000080 00000028
button/lid LID0 00000080 00000029

Looks like the number's incremental

Comment: Do it again but once, I need to check if an odd number implies opened or closed.

Comment: button/lid LID0 00000080 0000002e
button/lid LID0 00000080 0000002f

Now it's Hex :)

Comment: Ok, write a script with the following: `while true ; do grep close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state; done`, run it with `source my-script`, then close and open your laptop lid and tell me if there's any output.

Comment: OK, thanks. So it will watch whenever the lid state would actually write "closed". Then, what's next? How should it prevent the Desktop from locking? I was actually looking into the file: `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`. That would look nicer since there won't be a recursive program always scanning my drive, but a script that simply get read with an event. But, I still don't have the idea how to prevent the locking. Thanks for your giving this time though. I'll keep an eye on this.

Comment: I am on it, but could you tell if the script gave you any output after you closed the lid if so I already have written a script tailored for your need (using `crontab`). The problem is that in my laptop the button lid doesn't work so I need your input to verify if the solution I've written could work for you.

Comment: Yup, `grep` outputs "closed" whenever the lid is closed. What I can't make out is how to prevent the lock. I'm not sure what calls the lock, `gnome-screensaver`? Some way to prevent that from running during lid close, while lock over time is actually turned on? Thanks, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the information you provided in the comments is enough now.

First, you should install `xprintidle` (`sudo apt-get install xprintidle`), because we are going to try and emulate the locking mechanism!

Now, write a script (I've call it `screen-locker`, notice you don't need to put an extension to your filename):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:0.0

if /usr/bin/grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state ; then
  # the lid is closed, so nothing to do
  exit 0
fi

# The lid is open

# the idle time before locking is 60 minutes (60 times 60 times 1000 milliseconds)
lock_time_in_minutes=60

lock_time=$(( ${lock_time_in_minutes} * 60 * 1000 ))

if [ "`/usr/bin/xprintidle`" -ge "$lock_time" ] ; then
  /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -l
fi
```

Say you save it in a directory called `/home/your-username/bin`. Make it executable

```sh
chmod 755 /home/your-username/bin/screen-locker
```

now in the terminal run

```sh
echo '*/10 * * * * /home/your-username/bin/screen-locker' | crontab
```

to add this script to your crontab. (With this the script will be executed every 10 minutes.)

Now you can navigate to **Brightness & Lock** and deactivate the locking because the script will lock your screen if (and only if) the lid is open.

(You can change the `60` to `1` minute for the purpose of a quick test. You wait around 2 minutes with the lid open to see if it locks, then do the same waiting but with the lid closed to see if it does not lock).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you meant.

Comment: Thanks man! That idea was great. I edited the file to suit my needs. Below is script I made based on yours, which I then included in my Session Startup to be executed during login. Thanks a lot! Script: [screenlock](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0dbiel5oexinviy/screenlock)

Comment: I think that with crontab it is more efficient, also notice your vesion won't check if the lid is open or closed. I have edited my answer to reflect what you wanted to accomplish in your version.

Comment: One thing that prevents me from using crontab is that fact that it runs the script _every_ minute. In the version above (currently I'm using a newer one, with my own compiled, idle checker program) the program checks idleness every 10 minutes, without the need to read the hdd, since the whole script is maintained in memory, not exiting. And by the way, I needed to have my screen locked whether the lid is closed or not. So I removed that. Thanks.